# Incremental updates of data in an S3 data lake

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm new to AWS and coming from a Data Warehousing ETL background. We are currently moving to cloud using AWS services Data Lake and trying to load data into Amazon s3 landing layer (Bucket) from our external source RDBMS system using sqoop jobs and then to different layers (Buckets) in Amazon S3 using Informatica BDM.

The frequency of getting data from external source system is daily. I'm not sure how do we have to implement Delta load/SCD Types in S3. Is there any possibility to change an object after creating it in Amazon S3 bucket or do we have to keep creating copy of everyday load as an object in s3 bucket?

I understand Amazon gives us database options but we are directed to load data into Amazon S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon S3 is simply a storage system. It will store whatever data is provided.

It is *not* possible to 'update' an object in Amazon S3. An object can be overwritten (replaced), but it cannot be appended.

Traditionally, information in data lakes are appended by **adding additional files**, such as a daily dump of information. Systems that process data out of the data lake normally process multiple files. In fact, this is a more efficient process since data can be processed in parallel rather than attempting to read a single, large file.

So, your system can either do a new, complete dump that replaces data or it can store additional files with the incremental data.

Another common practice is to **partition** data, which puts files into different directories such as a different directory per month or day or hour. This way, when a system processes data in the data lake, it only needs to read files in the directories that are known to contain data for a given time period. For example, if a query wishes to processes data for a given month, it only needs to read the directory with data for that month, thereby speeding the process. (Partitions can also be hierarchical, such as having directories for hour inside day inside month.)

To answer your question of "how do we have to implement Delta load/SCD Types in S3", it really depends on **how you will use the data** once it is in the data lake. It would be good to store the data in a manner that helps the system that will eventually consume it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response John. As you mentioned, I will try to implement partitions which would be really useful for faster retrieval.